# Trying to switch views using a button only in a specific case

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Using a Parse Framework, I am trying to have a user login to an app and if the login works when the user presses the login button, I want the view to change. In this specific case if(!error) I want the view to switch. Assuming the second view is called PostingViewController, how could I make this work?

```
-(IBAction)signUpButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *userInput = usernameInputField.text;
    NSString *userPassword = passwordInputField.text;
    PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
    user.username = userInput;
    user.password = userPassword;
    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){ 

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"there was a problem");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply create an object of PostingViewController object and push it to the current navigationController

some thing similar to this might be of help...

```
PostingViewController *vc = [[PostingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your_nib_name" andBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc withAnimation:YES];
[vc release];
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, however when i use that code in the if statement I get "no visible interface for 'PostingViewController'" and "No visible interface for UINavigationController declares the selector pushViewController:withAnimation"

Comment: That fixed the error with pushViewController:withAnimation, so I must thank you for that :D. But now i get no interface declares the selector, initWithNibNameAndBundle

Comment: [[PostingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your_nib_name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    try this...

Comment: no errors, but the view doesn't seem to change even though the condition is being satisfied and the second view's view controller is called PostingViewController and is hooked up to the second view in interface builder.

Comment: R you sure that you initialized the navigationController to stack up your viewcontrollers in it?

Comment: I initialized a navigation Controller but didnt add any viewcontrollers to it, but i thought with the class name included in that method call wouldnt the navigation controller automatically push to the next view?